# Multiple Urls for Silent Post Response

Tags: authorize.net, silent-post

Can we somehow add two urls to Silent Post url field by inserting , or ; etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a plugin like IPN Redirect at https://wickedcoolplugins.com/the-plugins/ipn-redirect/ , have your Authorize.net silent post go to one common "Router" URL, which would then redirect (or "broadcast") it to your other web sites.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can only have one Silent Post URL.